# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to access SQL 2005 database.When I am trying to Login it is throwing the folllowing error.

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

I was connected to the DB and was working on the Queries/procs , when suddenly  i am unable to access the DB.

One of my Team mate at another center was able to get in.
Does it mean i am unable to access only my login?
Why does this happen?
Is there a  rememdy to this?

I am remotely accessing the SQL server via LAN.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You were actively connected and working and then all of a sudden you got that message?

"Does it mean i am unable to access only my login?"

try another login or ask someone else who has access.

Check with your admin and see if the instance itself is not responsive.

Comment: The Problem is that I have AdminAccess and the issue is with the Admin Login.

Comment: Just because you have admin access doesn't make you the admin.  Are you responsible for administering the instance?

Comment: one of my team mate checked it and he was able to access the DB.
So could  it mean that the error lies with my SQL DB instance ?

Comment: Does he use the same credentials (login) as you?  Is it integrated security or sql sercurity?  If its sqllogin try to login from his machine, if its integrated maybe your permissions were revoked.  If nothing else reboot, try again :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be a computer-specific issue, rather than SQL server. I've heard of software firewalls causing issues with connecting out on unlikely ports like SQL Server's Management Studio does.

Do you have any software firewalls enabled? It'd most probably be one with Program Control of some form such as Windows Firewall or Zonealarm.

If not, it's worth grabbing a network bod to double check there's nothing else interfering locally.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a TCP/IP connection to the database server and you know the port number (it is 1433 by default) then you can check the connectivity with this trick:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 1433
```

If the connection establishes then you should get a black screen.  If not, you get an error message.  This should be enough to check your network connection to the server is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have physical access to the machine to check it's still working? Could be simple hardware failure or power interruption.